# Remove selected element from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, events, state

I have input feild which takes a input (`interest`) from user and after hitting the *Enter key* adds the `interest` to the **`interests`** array. Then the elements in this array are displayed on screen via the `Domain` component as the user goes on adding. The `Domain` component contains an icon **`X`**  (cross) which on click should delete the  selected/clicked element from the array. Right now the last element in the array is getting removed after clicking.

How can I resolve this? Here is the code:

```
function Demo() {
  const [interest, setinterest] = useState("");
  const [interests, setinterests] = useState([]);

  const domainSelection = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter" && interest.length > 0) {
      setinterests((interests) => [...interests, interest]);
      setinterest("");
    }
  };

  const RemoveDomain = (e) => {
    var arr = [...interests];
    var index = arr.indexOf(e.target.value);
    arr.splice(index, 1);
    setinterests(arr);
  };

  const Domain = ({ interest }) => {
    return (
      <span>
        {interest}
        <span>
          <X onClick={RemoveDomain} />
        </span>
      </span>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>           
          <Input
            name="intersts"
            type="text"
            placeholder="eg Machine Learning .. "
            value={interest}
            required={true}
            onChange={(e) => setinterest(e.target.value)}
            className="interest-input inputs"
            onKeyDown={domainSelection}
          />
          {interests.map((interest, i) => (
            <Domain
              interest={interest}
              // Prevent duplicate keys by appending index:
              key={interest + i}
            />
          ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `e.target.value` is undefined.
Use Filter, This might help

```
const RemoveDomain = (value) => {
  var arr = interests.filter((item) => item !== value);
  setinterests(arr);
};

const Domain = ({ interest }) => {
  return (
    <span>
      {interest}
      <span>
        <X onClick={() => RemoveDomain(interest)} />
      </span>
    </span>
  );
};
```

Comment: Replaced the code with yours. I'm geting error: _TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined_